# Discord.py Not recognising the member intent

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot in python which gives the user a role if they enter the correct text.

The weird thing is, I have a code which, for some reason, doesn't work. I have imported member from discord, but when I run this specific code, it says `NameError: Member Not Defined.`

Imports:
`from discord import Member`

Code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    verify_channel = client.get_channel(#idgoeshere)
    verify_role = get(member.guild.roles, id='#idgoeshere')
    if message.content == 'Exo' in verify_channel:
        await member.add_roles(message.author, verify_role)
        await message.send(f'{message.author}, You have gained access to the other channels!')
```

I really don't know what the problem is, I have searched up on stackoverflow but there isn't much of these problems associating with this. My other discord bots work with the member function and importation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's because member isn't defined.
In your code, you have an on_message event, and you're getting the message. You can try defining member as `member = message.author`. You don't import member directly from discord. Because you are just importing the member class. I hope this helps answer your question.
P.S,  in the line `if message.content == 'Exo' in verify_channel:` that is not how you check if it is in that channel.
You need to have something like `if message.content == 'Exo' and message.channel verify_channel:`. I hope this helps too

Answer (score 0):

As your error states, you have not defined member. Member is usually used in commands and is defined, as seen here:

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx, member:discord.Member):
    await member.add_roles(verify_role)
```

However, since you are not using commands, this is not going to be your approach. It would be best to replace `member` with `message.author` instead, as this also gives you a [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20member#discord.Member) object. Have a look at the revised code below.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    verify_channel = client.get_channel(#idgoeshere)
    verify_role = get(member.guild.roles, id='#idgoeshere')
    if message.content == 'Exo' in verify_channel:
        await message.author.add_roles(verify_role)
        await message.send(f'{message.author}, You have gained access to the other channels!')

        # alternatively, you could add a separate variable such as
        # member = message.author
        # but using message.author on its own can be cleaner and clearer in this case
```

[image: Code working as expected]